# How handle Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, domparser

How can I handle error Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined. I'm using `DOMParser` to get `type` attribute of a xml tag. This xml tag sometimes can be `FirstTag` or other times can be `SecondTag`. I implement this that works fine with `FirstTag`, but when is `SecondTag` the error is shown in console.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var content = '<root>' + content + '</root>';
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content, "text/xml");

if( xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstTag")[0] == 'undefined' ){
    var element = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SecondTag")[0];
    var type = element.getAttribute("type");
}else {
    var element = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstTag")[0];
    var type = element.getAttribute("type");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `content` samples as well

Comment: Well content not always is the same xml, but always has `<Firstag type="something />` or `<SecondTag type="something" />`

Comment: The `if` condition never passes, `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstTag")[0]` will never be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstTag").length` instead of undefined check

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var content1 = '<root><FirstTag type="something" /></root>';
var content2 = '<root><SecondTag type="something" /></root>';

xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content2, "text/xml");

if( xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstTag").length == 0 ){
    var element = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SecondTag")[0];
    var type = element.getAttribute("type");
}else {
    var element = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstTag")[0];
    var type = element.getAttribute("type");
}
```